# Eliminar valores nulos o vacios de un JSON Object en Google AppScript

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy analizando informacion dentro de un Google Sheet por medio de Google App Script, mediante el rango total activo de la Hoja de Google obtengo un objeto javascript de tipo [multidimensional](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) a este mismo lo transformo en un objeto JSON con la funcion `JSON.stringify(miObjetoMultidimensional)`.

Obtengo un objeto que a su ves esta lleno de valores vacios, ya intente multiples formas de eliminarlos de mi objeto por que no los necesito pero no logro tener exito.

Tengo entendido que Google AppScript corre sobre [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino) por lo cual no puedo ejecutar funciones de flecha disponibles en ES6.

Esta es una parte del objeto obtenido en la salida de la funcion.

```
[  
 [  
      "asm-tree.jar",
      "",
      "",
      "commons-beanutils.jar",
      "",
      "",
      "commons-collections.jar",
      "",
      "",
      "util-java.jar",
      "",
      "",
      "bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar",
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   [  
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ],
   [  
      "\nDependencies",
      "",
      "",
      "\nDependencies",
      "",
      "",
      "\nDependencies",
      "",
      "",
      "\nDependencies",
      "",
      "",
      "\nDependencies",
      "",
      "",
      "\nDependencies"
   ],
   [  
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      ""
   ]
]
```

Intente pasando una funcion para validar el dato dentro del mismo `JSON.stringify()` pero los campos seguian apareciendo vacios.

Agrego mi funcion actual.

```
function listValues() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = activeSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var json = JSON.stringify(data,function(key, value) {
    if (value === '') { 
      return null; 
    } 
    return value; 
  });

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(json);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

Usa la función `filter`.

## Explicación

La función filter devuelve los elementos que cumplen con una condición. En el caso descrito, el objeto es un "array" de "arrays" por lo que deberás usar algun tipo de bucle para que recorra cada uno de los "arrays".

A continuacón un ejemplo usando `for` para fines de demostración rápida, usando Stacksnippet:

```js
var unObjeto = [
  [
    "asm-tree.jar",
    "",
    "",
    "commons-beanutils.jar",
    "",
    "",
    "commons-collections.jar",
    "",
    "",
    "util-java.jar",
    "",
    "",
    "bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "\nDependencies",
    "",
    "",
    "\nDependencies",
    "",
    "",
    "\nDependencies",
    "",
    "",
    "\nDependencies",
    "",
    "",
    "\nDependencies",
    "",
    "",
    "\nDependencies"
  ],
  [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ]
]

for(var i = 0; i< unObjeto.length;i++){
  unObjeto[i] = unObjeto[i].filter(function(n){ return n != "" }); 
}
console.log(unObjeto)
```

El código del OP quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
function listValues() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = activeSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i< data.length;i++){
    data[i] = data[i].filter(function(n){ return n != "" }); 
  }

  var json = JSON.stringify(data,function(key, value) {
    if (value === '') { 
      return null; 
    } 
    return value; 
  });


  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(json);

}
```

Comment: Me da como error:  No se puede encontrar la funcion filtro en el objeto.

Era algo que ya habia intentado. ¿A que crees que se deba ?

Comment: @MaxSandoval: Agrega el código que has intentado usando `filter` a la pregunta. Escribe un [mcve].

Comment: Ya quedo agregado. En teoria deberia funcionar para cualquier hoja de google, solo que la mia tiene varias tablas dentro de si misma los valores nulos son los espacio en blanco que hay dentro del rango de accion.

Comment: @MaxSandoval: En la función que agregaste no se incluye filter.

Comment: la funcion con filter la elimine ya, pero la trabaje directamente con el array que arroja el rango activo.

Comment: @MaxSandoval: Deberías haberla agregado, tal vez tuviste un error en la forma en que la usaste. De todas formas, edité mi respuesta para incluir al final el código con una modificación para usar filter.

Comment: Ya lo valide y funciono. Gracias Ruben.